# javascript function .change() not run on cloned element

Tags: javascript, jquery

i designed a dynamic table which user can add more row.
and there is a function .change() on an input
for the first row its run, but for next (cloned) elements the function doesn't run

my fiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/qp45z2f2/)

the code as follow

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
$("#btnAddItemAssignee").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();         
    $(".oAssignee:last").clone().insertAfter(".oAssignee:last");
    $(".oAssignee:last").find("#txtAssigneeType").val("");
    $(".oAssignee:last").find("#txtAssigneeId").val("");
});
});

$("body #txtAssigneeType").change(function(){
if ($(this).val()=="Individu")
{
    console.log($("body #txtAssigneeType").length);
    alert("call me");       
}
});
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/qp45z2f2/1/

Comment: Read about [`Event delegation`](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: __ID must be unique__

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution, it must be add `true` inside `.clone(true)`.

Comment: Yes passing true as a parameter it clones the data as well as events.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `$(".oAssignee:last").clone().insertAfter(".oAssignee:last");`

with

```
$(".oAssignee:last").clone("true").insertAfter(".oAssignee:last");
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Nofiden/qp45z2f2/4/)

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are using same Id for all drop-down.. #txtAssigneeType.. Change it when you are adding new group..

eg: add random id
     #txtAssigneeType1,
     #txtAssigneeType2,
     #txtAssigneeType3

Answer (score 0):

`.clone()` accepts two arguments. First one is for `"withDataAndEvents"` and second one is for `"deepWithDataAndEvents"`.

Both the values are false by default.

Change your statement to this and it will clone the data as well as events.

```
$(".oAssignee:last").clone(true).insertAfter(".oAssignee:last");
```

https://api.jquery.com/clone/